# In R and using Plotly how can I extract the dataframe related to the zoom-in tool?

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, r-plotly

This my code:

```
library(gapminder)

ggplotly(ggplot(gapminder %>% filter(country == "Chile")) + aes(x = year, y = pop) + geom_line())
```

Then I use the zoom in tool:

[image]

Then I have this output:

[image]

**My question is**: How can I access/extract the dataframe related to this output?

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need this: We can do it with `crosstalk`:

[image]

```
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(gapminder)

options(persistent = FALSE)

my_data <- SharedData$new(gapminder %>% filter(country == "Chile"))

my_plot <- plot_ly(my_data, x = ~ year, y = ~ pop, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_markers(alpha = 0.5) %>%
  highlight(on = "plotly_selected", off = "plotly_deselect", dynamic = TRUE)

my_table <- datatable(my_data)

bscols(widths = c(6, 4), my_plot, my_table)
```